# Lock copy-paste input to terminal while sudo prompts for password

Tags: command-line, sudo, password

**TL;DR**

Can you lock the copy-paste input into terminal while sudo is prompting for a password?

**More info**

Sometimes you want to copy and paste a long series of commands into the terminal and have them run sequentially. If `sudo` is part of any of the commands it prevents said command to run.

An example of this would be installing Spotify using the terminal commands provided on their website:

```
# 1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886

# 2. Add the Spotify repository
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

# 3. Update list of available packages
sudo apt-get update

# 4. Install Spotify
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Copy-pasting this into the terminal yields the following result:

```
user:~$ # 1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages
user:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user:
```

What happens is that the terminal interprets the line "# 2. Add the Spotify repository" as the provided password (or possibly even "" as a password as there's a line break between the sudo command and that line), locks for a few seconds while the copy-paste is still being input to the terminal, and then unlocks again for a second atempt at the password.

This is bad if you have a lot of commands you want to run in series, since then some of the non-sudo commands will be run while the sudo commands are denied.

A quick workaround to fix this is to manually write a nonsense command first, like `$ sudo whatever` , then enter the password, then paste the command series, like so:

```
user:~$ sudo whatever
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: whatever: command not found
user:~$ # 1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages
user:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
Executing: /tmp/tmp.JQ3ntmdbnL/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 
--recv-keys
BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
...
...
...
```

This works since the terminal instance will not prompt for a password again.

Is there a smarter way to do this? Can you i.e. lock the copy-paste input until a valid password has been provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are easy ways to do this.

Firstly, If you just want to get sudo permissions for subsequent commands, you can use `sudo -v` instead of `sudo whatever`. It caches your credentials without running a command.

---

Say you want to copy-paste this into terminal:

```
sudo echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
```

Normally this happens:

```
$ sudo echo 1
[sudo] password for wja: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for wja: 
1
```

Instead, you can use **braces**:

```
$ {
> sudo echo 1
> echo 2
> echo 3
> }
[sudo] password for wja: 
1
2
3
```

Or you can use **bash with a herestring**:

```
$ bash << EOF
> sudo echo 1
> echo 2
> echo 3
> EOF
[sudo] password for wja: 
1
2
3
```

Or (this might be the best option for untrusted input) you can have Bash **open an editor** then paste your snippet in there. The default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>. Paste your input into the editor, look it over, then close and save to run it.